# display image using jquery and ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

To display company details with image,
I have controller like:

```
public JsonResult PrintHeading()
        {
            CompanyModel cm = new CompanyModel();
            string qry = "select CompanyName,Address,ContactNo,EmailAddress,LogoFileName from tblCompanyInfo";
            DataTable dt = cls.LoadData(qry);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                        cm.CompanyName = Convert.ToString(dr["CompanyName"]);
                        cm.Address = Convert.ToString(dr["Address"]);
                        cm.ContactNo = Convert.ToString(dr["ContactNo"]);
                        cm.EmailAddress = Convert.ToString(dr["EmailAddress"]);
                        cm.LogoFileName = Path.Combine("\\Content\\Logo", Convert.ToString(dr["LogoFileName"]));
            }
            return Json(cm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

and Function:

```
function getPrintHeading() {
       var heading = '';
       $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Content("~/Bank/PrintHeading")',
           type: "GET",
           dataType: "JSON",
           async: false,
           success: function (headdata) {
               heading = '<img src="' + headdata.LogoFileName + '" width=50 height=50>' + headdata.CompanyName + '<br>' + headdata.Address + '<br>' + headdata.ContactNo + ', ' + headdata.EmailAddress ;
           }
       });
       return heading;                  

   }
```

It displays all other data but doesn't display image.please Can you give the idea?

Comment: Can you inspect your image in developer tools and see what url it is making? Also could you plz tell the image is in your virtual directory or out of virtual directory?

Comment: BDW where are you rendering your heading ? I mean your image

Comment: give us the source after ajax success .. to check it! you can capture it in google console or source tab in `inspector`

Comment: picture is in the folder Content\Logo at the location of project solution.

Comment: It is directly sent to the print page as HTML content.

Comment: var print_head = getPrintHeading();

Comment: this method in controller is working for:  @{
            var s = item.LogoFileName;
                    }
                    <img src="@Url.Content(item.LogoFileName)" width="100" height="100" />

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close img tag.Check it once may help You.

```
<img src="' + headdata.LogoFileName + '" width=50 height=50 />
```